# Sending Information from a Servlet to a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

ok this is what I'm trying to do...I have 1 JSP page that gets 2 integers from a user. I use a form in this JSP so I can send the information to the servlet with the doGet method.

Then I want to take those numbers find the greatest common denominator and send that to another JSP. Getting the GCD isnt the issue right now, I'll just use function. But I cant figure out how to send anything to a new JSP.

```
    request.setAttribute("TEST", "TESTING");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/JSP2.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Thats what I was playing around with to send information from the servlet to another JSP called JSP2. but whenever I hit submit on JSP (where I enter the numbers) I get an error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should include the error to help troubleshouting

Comment: Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

Comment: Not sure if you can make URL request for files in WEB-INF. Have yoy tried placing your JSP in WebContent (if you're using Eclipse, or other upper-level folder)?

Comment: the WEB-INF is in web content...and I'm using JDeveloper

Comment: Outside WEB-INF then. Put the JSP in the parent folder of WEB-INF and change the getRequestDispatcher parameter

Comment: still having the same problem. is there a way for the servlet to creat the new JSP page or something?

Answer (score 0):

Show us the directory structure of your project. Make an index.jsp page saying hello and see if you can access it.

How do you deploy the application, show us the .war unzipped contents.

Your idea to use the requestDispatcher is correct, as well as adding stuff to the request, and later in another servlet/jsp using them. Note that if you access the index.jsp by server:port/index.jsp then the requestDispatcher argument should also be "your.jsp" and not "WEB-INF/the.jsp", ie remove the WEB-INF.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking...but to get the numbers from the first JSP page I use:
`num1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));`
`num2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));`
in the doGet method

Answer (score 0):

If your form is `POST`ing to your servlet, shouldn't you be implementing `doPost` instead of `doGet`?